# Loop stops working and does not continue when the value is wrong

Tags: excel, loops, while-loop, vba

I am creating a code for sending email. The program will do a looping in every row and check whether the value in the first column is "yes" and then send the email.

The program seems work well when the value in every row is "yes", however it will stop the loop when there is 1 row empty or has other value than "yes" even though there are still some rows contain "yes" under that particular row.

I would be grateful if someone could help me

```
Sub SendMail()


Dim i As Integer


    i = 2

emailto = Cells((i + 1), 2).Text
    ccto = Cells((i + 1), 3).Text


While (Cells((i + 1), 1).value) = "yes"

Set outapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outmail = outapp.CreateItem(0)


With outmail
    .To = emailto
    .cc = ccto
    .BCC = ""
    .subject = "Subject"
    .Body = "bodytext"
    .Display
End with

   i = i + 1

Wend

Set outmail = Nothing
Set outapp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: That is because you are using `While`. The loop will terminate when it encounters the cell with value other than yes. As a result, rest of your rows are not processed. Use `do while true` and add `if (Cells((i + 1), 1).value) <> "yes"` Then exit do`. That said, your code needs correction at many levels.

Comment: To shahkalpesh's point about needing more corrections, try to avoid recreating the Outlook objects inside the loop.  Create them once. On the other hand, I assume you want to change emailto and ccto INSIDE the loop and then just set .To and .cc to those values.

I'm not sure that .Display is going to be nice - it's just going to open a mess of email windows.  I assume you're going to want that to .Send once you're done testing?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't looping through all of your items because your While condition is dependent on the values.

If your While condition was something more like i < uBound(Cells) or Cells.Count -1, it would continue processing.

You may want to consider a FOR or FOR EACH loop instead of WHILE.

Or, if it's feasible, sort your list so that all of the Yes values are first and leave this code as-is.  It'll look like you did it on purpose.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way (**NOT actual code just a prototype**)

```
'A loop to process through all rows of the table (For/Foreach)
'table.rows (depends upon your table type) (a datatable or whatever mode you are using)
For i=0 to table.rows-1 
    ' check for the field containing 'yes'
    If Cells((i + 1), 1).value) = "yes" Then
        'use continue to skip this record and continue with the next one
        Continue
    Else
        ' Process your e-mail
    End If
Next
```